# SpringDataJPA only save mapping table for Many to Many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have

- USER (user_id),
- LOCATION (location_id, country_id, state_id, city_id),
- COUNTRY(country_id, name),
- STATE(state_id, name)
- CITY(city_id, name).

There is a Many-to-Many relationship between USER and LOCATION through USER_LOCATION table. Here is my mapping in User.java:

```
//bi-directional many-to-many association to Location
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    name="user_location"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="LOCATION_ID")
        }
    )
private List<Location> locations;
```

When I am saving a USER, I only have USER.LOCATION.LOCATION_ID from the front end and I don't have other fields for LOCATION object. I only want to insert into USER_LOCATION table. But SpringDataJPA is trying to `insert into LOCATION with INSERT INTO LOCATION (CITY_ID, COUNTRY_ID, STATE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?) bind => [null, null, null]`

All the LOCATION, COUNTRY, STATE and CITY data are pre populated in the database, I don't want to insert any new record for these tables. How can I just insert into USER_LOCATION table?

Comment: are you saying that Location object should not be updated at any point in the future? If so set the mapping properties update=false, insert=false properties on @ManytoMany mapping

Answer (score 1):

> I only have USER.LOCATION.LOCATION_ID from the front end and I don't
>   have other fields for LOCATION object.

If you're associating the user with an existing location then you need to actually get that existing persistent Location from the database and set that as a relationship.

```
Location location = locationRepository.findById(locationId);
user.getLocations.add(location);
userRepository.persist(user);
```